# How to write property for formal verification?

Tags: system-verilog, formal-verification, system-verilog-assertions

```
property prop1;
@(posedge clk)
$fell(sig1) ##1 sequence1 |-> sequence2;
endproperty
```

I want to disable the property `iff sig1=1'b1` after first clock cycle.

Transition from high to low on `sig1` is my triggering condition. If I do `disable iff(sig1)` triggering condition will not be met.

Also using `throughout` is not possible on both enabling and satisfying sequences in formal verifiers.

How can i do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please be elaborate. Why you cannot use `disable iff (sig1);`?

Comment: transition from high to low on sig1 is my triggering condition. If i do disable iff(sig1) triggering condition will not be met.

Comment: Updated. Just a side note. Can you use nonoverlapping (|=>) operator such that only when $fell(sig1) evaluates to TRUE, then only sequence1 is evaluated? Like : `$fell(sig1) |=> sequence1 |-> sequence2;`

Comment: I am quite sure syntax wise its not possible and my question is different. disabling the property after one clock cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing some *satellite code* to derive a delayed version of `sig`:

```
  always @(posedge clk) sig1d <= sig1;

  property prop1;
    @(posedge clk) disable iff(sig1d) 
    $fell(sig1) ##1 sequence1 |-> sequence2;
  endproperty
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2tbX

Comment: if I am not wrong, it still delays the disable iff by one clock cycle from what i want to do.

Comment: But notice I still have `$fell(sig1)` NOT `$fell(sig1d)`. Surely, if you wanted to disable it even if `sig1` were high on the first clock cycle, then `$fell(sig1)` would never ever be true? Perhaps we need a timing diagram? (Or modify my code to produce one?)

Comment: @MatthewTaylor You've got to be careful with the fact that the `disable` expression is sampled asynchronously and can lead to race conditions. You should use `disable iff ($sampled(sig1d))`.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor : It seems the code given by you works for simulation(I did not try). But on formal tool, it leads to vacuous proof which means the enabling sequence cannot be realized.

Comment: @Tudor Thank you. So, `sig1d` will be driven in the _NBA_ region, `$fell(sig1)` will be sampled in the _preponed_ region and presumably the  `disable` evaluated (and hence `sig1d` sampled) in the _observed_ region, hence the race.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your assertion to only trigger if you don't see `sig1` high after the first cycle:

```
property prop1;
  @(posedge clk) disable iff(sig1d) 
    $fell(sig1) ##1 !sig1 ##0 sequence1 |-> sequence2;
endproperty
```

Comment: I have already tried this. The problem is, i cannot do it on sequence2.
For example:
    $fell(sig1) ##1 !sig1 throughout (sequence1) |-> sequence2;
But i cannot put throughout on sequence2(Formal tools do not allow that). So i thought best case is to disable the property on sig1 after one cycle. Any other suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: @kkdev From what I gather, you should rephrase your question, because it's ambiguous. You don't want want to disable the property if the `sig1` goes high after the first cycle (which can be construed as meaning the cycle after the first cycles). You want to disable it if `sig1` goes high in any subsequent cycle. You should try using @MathewTaylor's answer, as that's the only way.